What case is needed after 'играть в...'
I have seen examples of this verb used with the sport in question in both the accusative and prepositional case after 'играть в...'
Are both acceptable - I would have expected only the prepositional after 'в' - please see below
'Мой брат не любит играть в игры' where игры is accusative.

Can you please share the usage of the prepositional after играть в that you've seen? Thank you!

In the sense "to play some game or sport", играть в … only governs the accusative: играть в шашки, играть в футбол, играть в лапту etc.
The prepositional can indeed be used after this construct, but the sense will be different: it will mean "to play somewhere": играть в лесу "to play in the woods", играть в детском саду "to play in the daycare" etc. The noun that you put in the prepositional is not the object, but the complement.
You can even mix the two: играть в салки в лесу "to play tag in the woods", играть в шахматы в школе "to play chess in the school" etc.

On top of Quassnoi's answer, some games appear in the nominative after "играть в...": играть в дочки-матери, в солдатики, в казаки-разбойники.

It's a weird case indeed, but I don't think that this case being the nominative is universally accepted. The corpus and most grammars treat it as "secondary accusative" (второй винительный), in Zaliznyak's work there are only pros and contras without any definite judgement.
